# Remove everything in a line before comma

Tags: sed

I have multiple files with lines like:

```
foo, 123456
bar, 654321
baz, 098765
```

I would like to remove everything on each line before (and including) the comma.
The output would be:

```
123456
654321
098765
```

I attempted to use the following after seeing something similar on another question, but the user didn't leave an explanation, so I'm not sure how the wildcard would be handled:

```
find . -name "*.csv" -type f | xargs sed -i -e '/*,/d'
```

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**METHOD 1:**
If it's always the *2nd* column you want, you can do this with *awk* -- this command is actually splitting the rows on the whitespace rather than the comma, so it gets your second column -- the numbers, but without the leading space:

```
awk '{print $2}' < whatever.csv
```

**METHOD 2:**
Or to get everything *after the comma* (including the space):

```
sed -e 's/^.*,//g' < whatever.csv
```

**METHOD 3:**
If you want to find all of the **.csv** files and get the output of all of them together, you can do:

```
sed -e 's/^.*,//g' `find . -name '*.csv' -print`
```

**METHOD 4:**
Or the same way you were starting to -- with *find* and *xargs*:

```
find . -name '*.csv' -type f -print | xargs sed -e 's/^.*,//'
```

**METHOD 5:**
Making all of the **.csv** files into .**txt** files, processed in the way described above, you can make a brief shell script.  Like this:

Create a script "*bla.sh*":

```
#!/bin/sh
for infile in `find . -name '*.csv' -print` ; do
        outfile=`echo $infile | sed -e 's/.csv/.txt/'`
        echo "$infile --> $outfile"

        sed -e 's/^.*,//g' < $infile > $outfile
done
```

Make it executable by typing this:

```
chmod 755 bla.sh
```

Then run it:

```
./bla.sh
```

This will create a **.txt** output file with everything after the comma for each **.csv** input file.

**ALTERNATE METHOD 5:**
Or if you need them to be named **.csv**, the script could be updated like this -- this just makes an output file named "**file-new.csv**" for each input file named "**file.csv**":

```
#!/bin/sh
for infile in `find . -name '*.csv' -print` ; do
    outfile=`echo $infile | sed -e 's/.csv/-new.csv/'`
    echo "$infile --> $outfile"

    sed -e 's/^.*,//g' < $infile > $outfile
done
```

Comment: What if it's multiple files?

Comment: Do you want the output back into new files, or just output to the screen?

Comment: new files, same name

Comment: Ok see the updated answer (and accept if it covers your need).  The last method makes an new .csv file for each original .csv file, but doesn't overwrite the original file (safer that way).

Comment: you should really learn about `-exec` option... see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice

Comment: -exec option I didn't include because it makes a very messy command line with output redirection and creating new output files.  Plus the xargs version is equally efficient and much simpler to read.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work for a single file.  Let's say the
input is 'yourfile' and you want the output to go to 'outfile'.

```
sed 's/^.*,//' < yourfile > outfile
```

The syntax to do a search-and-replace is `s/input_pattern/replacement/`

The `^` anchors the input pattern to the beginning of the line.

A dot `.` matches any single character; `.*` matches a string of zero or more of any character.

The `,` matches the comma.

The replacement pattern is empty, so whatever matched the input_pattern
will be removed.

Comment: What if it's multiple files?